# How to access attributes from a child module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i'm working on a sort of custom-rolled history tracking for a RoR application. The part i'm hung up on is getting the logged in users information to tie to the record. I've figured out getting the user, its by a submodule which is attached to the `ActionController::Base` class. The problem is, I'm having trouble retrieving it from the submodule.

Here is my code:

```
module Trackable


  # This is the submodule
  module TrackableExtension

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    attr_accessor :user

    included do
      before_filter :get_user
    end

    def get_user
      @user ||= current_user # if I log this, it is indeed a User object
    end
  end




  # Automatically call track changes when 
  # a model is saved
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do 
    after_update :track_changes
    after_destroy :track_destroy
    after_create :track_create
    has_many :lead_histories, :as => :historical
  end


  ### ---------------------------------------------------------------
  ### Tracking Methods

  def track_changes
    self.changes.keys.each do |key|
      next if %w(created_at updated_at id).include?(key)

      history = LeadHistory.new
      history.changed_column_name = key
      history.previous_value = self.changes[key][0]
      history.new_value = self.changes[key][1]
      history.historical_type = self.class.to_s
      history.historical_id = self.id
      history.task_committed = change_task_committed(history)
      history.lead = self.lead

      # Here is where are trying to access that user.
      # @user is nil, how can I fix that??
      history.user = @user

      history.save
    end
  end
```

In my models then its as simple as:

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Trackable
    # other stuff
end
```

Comment: How are you include this in your models?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a submodule at all? I think all of the code inside submodule can work living directly in the main module too.

Comment: The reason why is that I needed to be able to export that to the `ActionController::Base` so I could attach to controller functions to get the `current_user`, and keep the main module away from it because it would error out if I sent a module to `ActionController::Base` that had methods like: `included { after_update :some_method }` because `ActionController::Base` does not respond to methods like `after_update`

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by setting a `Trackable` module variable.

In my `TrackableExtension::get_user` method I do the following:

```
def get_user
    ::Trackable._user = current_user #current_user is the ActionController::Base method I have implemented
end
```

Then for the `Trackable` module I added:

```
class << self
    def _user
        @_user
    end

    def _user=(user)
        @_user = user
    end
end
```

Then, in any `Trackable` method I can do a `Trackable::_user` and it gets the value properly.